# PHPMailer fails to send email

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am creating PHP Class to send email. Problem is that for some reason mail is not sending. Does someone know where is the problem?

I am running this on XAMPP

Here is the code:

```
include_once "class.sendMAIL.php";
$sendActivation = new sendMAIL();
$body="http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/activation.php?id=$activationCode";
if ($sendActivation->sendActivationEmail($name, $email,$body))
{
    echo "MAIL SENT";
}
else {
    echo "ERROR IN SENDING";
}
```

Mail class:

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
class sendMAIL {
    private $sendEmail;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->sendEmail =  new PHPMailer();
        $this->sendEmail->isSMTP();      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $this->sendEmail->Host = ' smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $this->sendEmail->SMTPAuth = true;    // Enable SMTP authentication
        $this->sendEmail->Username = 'my@gmail.com';    // SMTP username
        $this->sendEmail->Password = 'mypassword';           // SMTP password
        $this->sendEmail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';     // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
        $this->sendEmail->port ="465";
        $this->sendEmail->From = "";
        //$this->sendEmail->FromName = $name;
        $this->sendEmail->isHTML(true);
    }

    public function sendActivationEmail($name, $email, $link) {
        $this->sendEmail->AddAddress($email);
        $this->sendEmail->Subject="Aktivacija";
        $body="Follow this link to activate your account: <a href='$link' />LINK</a>";
        $this->sendEmail->MsgHTML($body);
        if($this->sendEmail->send()) {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }       
    }
}
```

THIS IS ERROR WHAT I GOT WHEN I DEBUGGED PROBLEM:

```
You must provide at least one recipient email address.
```

Thanks to @paulgv I fixed error but now I got this error:

```
SMTP connect() failed
```

Does someone knows where's the problem?

EDIT: problem caused gmail. gmail blocked my webapp to access my email.

Comment: how do you know its not sending? (not receiving is not the same as not sending)

Comment: so you get false back? then you should check  `$this->sendEmail->ErrorInfo` for details. and/or look at your mail server's logs to see if/why the mail was rejected

Comment: I tried... I "debug" if mail is sent from class that calls sendMAIL class and output is FALSE

Comment: `Host = ' smtp.gmail.com';` Does whitespace matter there?

Comment: @developerwjk yes it is but I got this error when I am debuggin "You must provide at least one recipient email address."

Comment: What's the value of `$email` when you call `sendActivationEmail()` ?

Comment: I echo it and it's valid email address @paulgv

Comment: Alright, I also find this line weird in your code : `$this->sendEmail->AddAddress=($email);` maybe try with `$this->sendEmail->AddAddress($email);` instead ?

Comment: @paulgv thank you. Now I don't have this error but insted I got this one: SMTP connect() failed

my password and username are correct...

Comment: @paulgv answer on my question and I will mark it as a correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the answer, copied from the comment I posted earlier ;)

Alright, I also find this line weird in your code : `$this->sendEmail->AddAddress=($email);` maybe try with `$this->sendEmail->AddAddress($email);` instead ?

Now, concerning your SMTP authentication issue, did you try enabling verbose mode ? Might help !
According to the documentation, you should do something like this :

```
$this->sendEmail->SMTPDebug = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the SMTP authentification issue, try this :

```
$this->sendEmail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$this->sendEmail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$this->sendEmail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$this->sendEmail->Port       = 587;
```

It's working for me.